PEAR binary directory is empty
I'm setting up my php setup, and I decided to install PEAR but even following the official installation I couldn't install. I downloaded PEAR manually through https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar followed the installation, added the path '/home/Thiago/pear/bin' to the environment variable, I tried to access the binary through the path '/home/Thiago/pear/bin/pear' but the directory is empty, I'm currently using arch Linux and these are the installation paths, could you help me.

Installation base ($prefix)                   : /home/Thiago/pear
Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
Binaries directory                            : /home/Thiago/pear/bin
PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /home/Thiago/pear/share/pear
Documentation directory                       : /home/Thiago/pear/docs
Data directory                                : /home/Thiago/pear/data
User-modifiable configuration files directory : /home/Thiago/pear/cfg
Public Web Files directory                    : /home/Thiago/pear/www
System manual pages directory                 : /home/Thiago/pear/man
Tests directory                               : /home/Thiago/pear/tests
Name of configuration file                    : /home/Thiago/.pearrc

echo $PATH
/home/Thiago/pear/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/Thiago/pear/bin:/home/Thiago/pear/bin/pear
uname -srm
Linux 6.9.8-arch1-1 x86_64
I've already tried to add the path in Zsh either by "path+='/.../' I also changed the ~/.zshrc and I also tried to look for the binary that was missing but I didn't find it in the system using "whereis"

I forget to say, my PHP version is 8.3.9, i notice in my console that has 2 error mensage,

[PEAR] PEAR: Invalid tag order in , found <_content> expected one of "group"

[PEAR] PEAR: Parsing of package.xml from file "/tmp/pear/temp/pear6skih0/package.xml" failed

After some searches, I found that people were experiencing similar errors with PHP 8.3.8 in the libxml2 update. I'll try change the libxml2 version

I'm still checking if the bug itself was caused by the "libxml2" library I'm trying to change to a previous version with the "downgrade" but from what I've read changing package versions can compromise some dependencies

I managed to solve the problem! it really was libxml2

This was fixed upstream in versions 8.2.22 and 8.3.10.  To make it work on older versions (I've tested 7.3 and 7.4 series), apply the patch from the issue to PHP:
diff --git a/ext/xml/compat.c b/ext/xml/compat.c
index 7b463ebb5112e..7ca015acc5421 100644
--- a/ext/xml/compat.c
+++ b/ext/xml/compat.c
@@ -375,7 +375,7 @@ _get_entity(void *user, const xmlChar *name)
        if (ret == NULL)
            ret = xmlGetDocEntity(parser->parser->myDoc, name);
 
-       if (ret == NULL || (parser->parser->instate != XML_PARSER_ENTITY_VALUE && parser->parser->instate != XML_PARSER_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) {
+       if (ret == NULL || parser->parser->instate == XML_PARSER_CONTENT) {
            if (ret == NULL || ret->etype == XML_INTERNAL_GENERAL_ENTITY || ret->etype == XML_INTERNAL_PARAMETER_ENTITY || ret->etype == XML_INTERNAL_PREDEFINED_ENTITY) {
                /* Predefined entities will expand unless no cdata handler is present */
                if (parser->h_default && ! (ret && ret->etype == XML_INTERNAL_PREDEFINED_ENTITY && parser->h_cdata)) {


i have the exactly same problem, and also i tried to install it from AUR (php-pear package) and didn't work either (neither pear nor pecl commands are found).

Hello @mohachi, As you didn't gave a solution to the problem described in the question, I suggest you to add this as a comment rather than here :)

I can't because of my reputation under 50, thanks
